# Reduced homolgy groups of a sum of open spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to prove the following implication:

Let $X=A_1\cup\dots\cup A_n$, where $A_i$ is open for every $i=1,\dots,n$. and for every set of indices $i_1,\dots,i_k$ set $A_{i_1}\cap\dots\cap A_{i_k}$ is either empty or has trivial reduced homology groups.
Prove that $\tilde{H_i}(X)=0$ for $i\ge n-1$.

I wanted to use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. We have $H_m(\bigcap A_i)=0$ for every m. From the assumption we also have $H_m(A_1)\oplus\dots\oplus H_m(A_n)=0$. So hence we have sequence that looks like
$\dots\rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow H_m(X)\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 0\dots$

So hence $H_m(X)$ is also 0, even for every $m$. But it doesn't look good for me - the intersections may be empty for example.. But I think that trivial homologies of intersections would be ok I think (a point for example). I suppose that assumptions are too weak to use this theorem in that form. I'm want to try to use an induction also. Any hints or comments?

Just to be clear - my main problem is whether I can use the M-V sequence or not? I think that empty intersection is the problematic place, while trivial reduced homologies could be ok (eg. one-point intersection). Both cases are covered by the assumptions, right?

Thanks